# iframe form submit opens in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I am loading a form in an iframe within another iframe.  The form submit normally opens in the same window but seemingly due to the double iframe situation it now opens in a new tab.

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="POST" name="myform" id="myform" target="_parent">
...
</form>
```

I have no control over the form or js within it.  The only trouble here is that I end up with my original iframe still open in a tab with no content which looks awkward.  Is there a way to trigger an event with jQuery or straight js so that my original window will close when the form opens a new tab?  Or better yet - is there any way to manipulate the js inside the form so that it works as expected and open within the same window?

Comment: You can intercept the "submit" event of a form -- but could you post an example structure of your nested iframes?

Comment: From first glance: The form is inside an iframe, which is inside an iframe. You want the submit event to reload the outer iframe?

Comment: I'd like do *something* in the outermost page when the submit event happens in the innermost iframe.  In other words, something like `$('iframe').on('submitevent', function() { doSomething(); });`.